# How to generate password protected (as optional) zip file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, zip, rubyzip

Basic archive creation works like this (using rubyzip)

```
Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, create: true) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |filename|
    zipfile.add(filename, File.join(folder, filename))
  end
end
```

Okay I got that to work a while back... But now I need to create a password-protected zip. For this the documentation has:

```
enc = Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new('password')
buffer = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(encrypter: enc) do |output|
  output.put_next_entry("my_file.txt")
  output.write my_data
end
```

Which I don't quite understand how to combine with the first approach (iterating over a list of files).

Also password is optional in my case - it's a user choice whether the archive will be password protected or not. I would like to avoid having to use a completely different code in each case.

Comment: Note that `Zip::TraditionalEncrypter` is almost equivalent to no encryption at all. It was an ad hoc encryption method developed in the early 1990's, was poorly designed, and is easily broken. If you need your data to be _actually_ secure to some degree, then use an OpenSSL cipher, such as AES, on the entire zip file.

Comment: I read some comments to that extent but when I was looking up ways to decrypt passworded zips without the password it was all about brute-forcing the password. How can you actually break the encryption?

Comment: There are [fast plaintext attacks](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-60590-8_12) on the encryption. Implementation [here](https://github.com/kimci86/bkcrack).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [by default](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/blob/f811b2d00e04d41d702398efe3fb54dbac892826/lib/zip/output_stream.rb#L32) encrypter is `nil`

But you can pass it dynamically if needed

I suggest such method:

```rb
require "zip"

def zipfile(filenames:, zip_filename:, password: nil)
  # If password was passed, intitialize encrypter
  encrypter = Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new(password) if password

  # Create buffer, it is the object like StringIO
  # Pass encrypter there, it will be nil if no password
  buffer = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(encrypter: encrypter) do |out|
    Array(filenames).each do |filename|
      # Create file inside zip archive
      out.put_next_entry(File.basename(filename))
      # And fill with file content
      out.write File.read(filename)
    end
  end

  # Write result to the zip file
  File.open(zip_filename, "w") { |zipfile| zipfile.write(buffer.string) }
end
```

Of course you can modify it or create separate entity for you needs

Now you can call this method passing string or array of filenames, passing/not passing password

```rb
zipfile(filenames: ["1.txt", "2.txt"], zip_filename: "new.zip", password: "123456")
zipfile(filenames: "/Users/abc/111.txt", zip_filename: "/Users/abc/111.zip")
```

As I see this is pretty new feature of rubyzip 3.0 and you need to specify this version (for example in the `Gemfile`)

```rb
# Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rubyzip", "3.0.0.alpha"
```

And run your script in the context of that version, let's say

```
bundle exec ruby zipper.rb
```